# How does regex_path_filter work in GCSFile properties of DATA FUSION pipeline in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

IN Data fusion pipeline of GCP, the GCSFile properties having a field named "Regex path filter". How does it work?. I don't get proper documentation on this.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the regex documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

How does it work? It is applied to the filenames and not to the whole path.

For example, lets say you have the following path: `gs://<my-bucket>/<my/complete/path>/` and you have some CSV and JSON files inside this path.

To filter only the CSV files you would use the regex `.*\.csv`

Please note that this regex will **only** filter what starts after your path.